# Background image stopping after footer

Tags: css, image, background, footer, repeat

Hi I need help on a website. The background image is stopping at the footer which means on long pages I get an ugly section underneath instead of the background continuing below. I tried using padding-bottom however then I get padding on the pages I do not need it on,

Where as homepage is longer so no problems and website bounces on the footer.

Stage site addy - http://stage.microscooterstore.co.uk/mss/

Problem page example: http://stage.microscooterstore.co.uk/mss/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `<html/>`, `<body/>` and `.ma-wrapper` a `height` of `100%`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.ma-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: he also needs to add `min-height: 100%` to `#ma-wrapper`

Comment: Amazing Thanks - Working now, lost a lot of hair over that

Answer (score 0):

Your container `.ma-wrapper` does not extend to the bottom of the page.

```
.ma-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```